# Symfony 6.4 Embed Form data loss after re-submit

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony-forms

I have a problem with Symfony 6.4 forms.

I have a `FirstType` form that has only one field of type `CollectionType` with an entry type `SecondType`. `SecondType` has several fields (`NumberType`, `TextType`...)

Finally, I have a Stimulus controller to manage the dynamic addition of children (`SecondType`) to the parent form (`FirstType`).

When I add elements and submit the form, if no errors are detected (via Symfony constraints), then everything is fine and my childrens are persisted in my parent entity.

On the other hand, if I have any errors, the form is displayed again to show me these errors (this behavior is desired).

From now on, whether I correct my errors or not, when I resubmit the form, my `Request` contains only the 1st child (the others are no longer in the `Request`).

If anyone has already encountered this problem and has an answer/idea, I'd love to hear from you!

`FirstType.php` (Parent FormType) :

```php
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\FirstEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

final class FirstType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('childrens', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type' => SecondType::class,
                'entry_options' => [
                    'label' => false,
                    'container_model' => $builder->getData(),
                ],
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'by_reference' => false,
                'required' => true,
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver
            ->setDefaults([
                'data_class' => FirstEntity::class,
            ])
        ;
    }
}
```

`SecondType.php` (Child FormType) :

```php
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\SecondEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\IntegerType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

final class SecondType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('rowLetter', ChoiceType::class)
            ->add('quantity', IntegerType::class)
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver
            ->setDefaults([
                'data_class' => SecondEntity::class,
            ]);
    }
}
```

`form/form-collection-table_controller.js` (Stimulus Controller) :

```js
import { Controller } from '@hotwired/stimulus'

export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = ['collectionContainer']

  connect () {
    this.prototypeValue = this.element.dataset.formCollectionPrototypeValue
    this.indexValue = parseInt(this.element.dataset.formCollectionIndexValue) || 0
    this.deleteButtonTextValue = this.element.dataset.formCollectionDeleteButtonTextValue

    if (document.referrer !== window.location.href) {
      this.addCollectionElement()
    }
  }

  addCollectionElement (event) {
    const tableRow = document.createElement('tr')

    tableRow.innerHTML = this.prototypeValue.replace(/__name__/g, this.indexValue.toString())

    const actionColumn = document.createElement('td')

    const deleteButton = document.createElement('button')
    deleteButton.type = 'button'
    deleteButton.textContent = this.deleteButtonTextValue
    deleteButton.className = 'btn btn-danger float-end'
    deleteButton.dataset.action = 'click->form--form-collection-table#removeCollectionElement'
    actionColumn.appendChild(deleteButton)

    tableRow.appendChild(actionColumn)

    this.collectionContainerTarget.appendChild(tableRow)
    this.indexValue++
  }

  removeCollectionElement (event) {
    const tableRow = event.target.closest('tr')

    if (tableRow) {
      this.collectionContainerTarget.removeChild(tableRow)
    }
  }
}
```

`EmbedCollectionController.php` (Controller) :

```php
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\FirstEntity;
use App\Form\FirstType;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class EmbedCollectionController extends AbstractController
{
    public function indexAction(Request $request, int $id): Response
    {
        // ...

        $form = $this->createForm(FirstType::class, $firstEntity);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $this->entityManager->persist($firstEntity);
            $this->entityManager->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('app_index');
        }

        return $this->render('index.html.twig', [
            'firstEntity' => $firstEntity,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
}
```

`index.html.twig` (Twig view) :

```html
{% block content %}
<!-- ... -->

<tbody {{ stimulus_target('form--form-collection-table', 'collectionContainer') }}>
{% for children in form.childrens %}
    <tr>
        {{ form(children) }}
        <td>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger float-end" {{ stimulus_action('form--form-collection-table', 'removeCollectionElement') }}>
                Remove
            </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</tbody>

<!-- ... -->
{% endblock %}
```